# extract lines using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I want to get following information from given text

```
Mohsan,Hasan    ADDRESS 123-456789
ABCD,EFGHIJKL   ADDRESS 123-456789
AB,XYZFGH   ADDRESS 123-456789
```

Get lines which have first name of 3-5 characters and last name of exact 5 characters

Comment: Using what?  `grep`?  `perl`?

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,5},[a-zA-Z]{5}\s
```

or in some environments/programming languages

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,5},[a-zA-Z]{5}\\s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be unicode compatible:

```
^\p{L}{3,5},\p{L}{5}\s
```